# How to solve TCP server address already in use error

Tags: c, networking, tcp, network-programming

I am writing a TCP concurrent server which will fork a child process to deal with every new connection. Suppose *ClientA* is interacting with *ChildA* while *server* is still listening on same port. In case we kill *server* with say SIGINT signal, *ClientA* and *ChildA* keep on interacting.

So, in that situation if I restart my *server*, it obviously throws `Address already in use` on `bind` function call.

What are all possible solutions to this issue and which one is usually followed?

Answer (score 2):

2 options.

1. `kill` *ChildA* processes when *server* is killed.
2. `close` the `fd` used to `listen`/`bind` in *ChildA* as soon as the `fork` is done.

Comment: Neither of those will solve the problem. The problem here is ports in the `TIME_WAIT` state, which isn't addressed by your answer.

Comment: I agree with the *SO_REUSEADDR*, but in my initial reading of the question I read it as "children continue living once *server* is killed", which means the port is still being listened on when *server*  is restarted. *SO_REUSEADDR* will not help in that case.

Comment: I doubt after killing server child goes into TIME_WAIT state. They are both interacting fine.

Comment: Exactly. Since *ChildA* inherit's *server*'s opened fds *ChildA* should still have *listenfd* opened. I suspect this to be true, going to go test and see if this is the case...

Comment: Yes, this is the case. Between I already close fd used to listen in child process before anything starts. Your second point isn't useful. How you propose to kill every child process when parent receives a SIGINT. Can you explain on that part ? First point seems to be 1 solution. Ideally server would have liked child to continue but still listen to new connections. But I guess that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: maintain a list of active children and `kill()` each one.

Comment: You mean in a signal handler ? yes looks possible. Let me check.. thank you.

Comment: As I commented on answer by @EJP `SO_REUSEADDR` will still be necessary to `bind` while still in `TIME_WAIT`.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to do from signal handler, those should be short and fast. More like set a flag in signal handler and check it in  main body of code.

Comment: Correction. He certainly needs to close the listening socket in the forked child process, or make sure it isn't inherited.

Answer (score 1):

Set the socket option `SO_REUSEADDR` on the listening socket before you bind it.

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR isn't helping here because both client and server child are interacting. SO_REUSEADDR is just useful for TIME_WAIT state.

Comment: Hi rakesh, With this comments looks like i dont understand problem. Is ur client is not getting disconnected ? all new connection will be able to connect when reuseraddr will be used

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR is essential but doesn't address the issue above. SO_REUSEADDR is essential for case when I explicitly kills both server and child. client will be in TIME_WAIT state so connection is still bound and being used. I have tried this situation yet, but am trying it out.

Comment: @raskesh.pandit You need both SO_REUSEADDR and close or not inherit the listening socket in the child (forked) process.